# How to save multiple dynamically created forms in django

Tags: django, django-forms, htmx

I am trying to create a page where various data corresponding to mutliple models can be input by the user, and to have an option to dynamically add additional forms. I have been attempting to use htmx for this and am able to dynamically add forms, however when I save it is only the last entered form that is saved. I haven't used formsets as this wont integrate well with htmx https://justdjango.com/blog/dynamic-forms-in-django-htmx#django-formsets-vs-htmx.

Code below any suggestion as to how to get all the dynamically created forms to be save would be most appreciated!

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Book, Author
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper


class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-CaseForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

views.py

```
class create_book(TemplateView):
    
    template_name = 'create_book.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        author_form = AuthorForm
        book_form = BookForm
        return self.render_to_response(
            {'book_form': BookForm,
             "author_form": AuthorForm,}
        )
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        author_form = AuthorForm(data=self.request.POST)
        book_form = BookForm(data=self.request.POST)
        if author_form.is_valid():
            author = author_form.save()
            if book_form.is_valid():
                book = book_form.save(commit=False)
                book.author = author
                book.save()

def create_book_form(request):
    form = BookForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "partials/book_form.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create_book/', create_book.as_view(), name='create-book'),
    path('htmx/create-book-form/', create_book_form, name='create-book-form'),]
```

create_book.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form  class="blueForms" id="id-CaseForm" method="post" >
{% crispy author_form %}

{% crispy book_form %}
<button type="button" hx-get="{% url 'create-book-form' %}" hx-target="#bookforms" hx-swap="beforeend">
    Add book form
</button>
<div id="bookforms"></div>
</form>
```

partials/book_form.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">

{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}
{{ form.management_form }}

</div>
```

Comment: Use formsets for this

Comment: Thanks @Swift, that is what I have done previously but these wont work well with htmx

Comment: Why don't you create your own form template?

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to this question. Please let me know if you find it.

Comment: @Jesramz I've given up and am just using javascript

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google finds me this module:

https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx

It seems someone may have already done this for you my friend :)

Comment: Where in django-htmx does it talk about forms?

Comment: @Jesramz I don't think this is an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def b(request):
    return render(request, 'b.html')

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import Author, Book

@csrf_exempt  # For demonstration purposes, disable CSRF protection; do not use in production
def display_form_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        author_name = request.POST.get('author_name')
        book_titles = request.POST.getlist('book_name[]')

        # Create an instance of the Author model and save the author's name
        author_instance = Author(name=author_name)
        author_instance.save()

        # Add book titles to the Author instance
        for title in book_titles:
            # Create and save a Book instance for each title, associating it with the author
            book = Book(title=title, author=author_instance)
            book.save()

        # Print the values to the terminal
        print(f'Author Name: {author_name}')
        print('Book Titles:')
        for title in book_titles:
            print(title)

        return HttpResponse('Form data saved and displayed in terminal.')

    return render(request, 'index.html')



index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/htmx/1.9.5/htmx.min.js" integrity="sha512-2NwoAICmYEIEuayBZdfd/cEvYGevbb1jezvQli/Iw052KfAA3NGrXAH2AY02cjt3gMdui5Q8nKauPYgVOE+pmg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black; color: white;">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'display_form_data' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="author_name">Author Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="author_name" name="author_name" required>
        <br>
        <button hx-get="{% url 'b' %}" hx-target="#b" hx-swap="beforeend">+</button>
        <br><hr>
        <div id="b"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>



   b.html


    <label for="book_name">Book Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="book_name" name="book_name[]" required>
    <br>




from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  
    path('', views.index, name='create_author'),
    path('b/', views.b, name='b'),
      path('display_data/', views.display_form_data, name='display_form_data'),
  
    
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).